# Getting a SIGSEGV run time error despite initialization and proper bounds?

Tags: c, combinations

My solution to http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/golf/minimal-combinatorial/description/ problem on hackerearth:

```
#include <stdio.h>
signed long long int fn(int,int);
int main()
{ 
 int t=0,n=0,r=0,i=1;
 signed long long int c=0;
 scanf("%d",& t);
 for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
   {
     scanf("%d",&n);
     scanf("%d",&r);
     c=fn(n,r);
     printf("%lld\n",c);

   }
}

signed long long int fn(int n,int r)
{
 if (r==1)
   return n;
 else if (r==0)
   return 1;
 else return (fn(n-1,r)+fn(n-1,r-1));
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't, it reads the correct integer (scanf uses "%d" as the format specifier)

Comment: why are you declaring `r` and `n` as arrays, but only use the index 0 of them?

Comment: How can you ensure proper bounds if you're using `scanf` and not error checking?

Comment: @Fiddling sorry couldn't get you (by proper bounds I meant array bounds and now I've removed arrays)

Comment: @user3632784 Sorry.  You are (were) relying on the user to enter the number of elements in the array and using this unfiltered number.  This could lead to accessing memory outside the bounds of your arrays.

Comment: Format your code correctly.

Comment: BTW how can you get a SIGSEGV with code that doesn't even compile (?!)

Comment: @MichaelWalz it compiles ! do you see any mistake?

Comment: Yes I see at least one mistake: `if r==1 return n;` is not valide C code. `if (r==1) return n;` would be  correct. And please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You get segmentation fault because you have infinite recursion, make sure that the stop conditions in the recursive function cover all cases.

You can see what's happening either in the debugger or simply by printing the two parameters at the beginning of `fn()`.

Comment: Yep. After fixing the broken code I get a stack overflow here.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
scanf("%d",n);
scanf("%d",r);
```

should be replaced by :

```
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&r);
```

`scanf` expects the **pointer** to the variables where the scanned value should go, not the value itself.

Comment: oops!thanks for pointing that out.But still while calculating 100c10 it shows same error.